# Checkboxes to toggle text on and off

Tags: javascript

I want to use a checkbox to change the visibility of a paragraph in JavaScript. I would like to do this in pure JavaScript and not use any librararies like jQuery. Furthermore, I would like to do it in JSFiddle.

I know that one viable solution is to use: document.formName.checkboxName.checked like so:

```
 function show { 
    document.getElementById("paragraphName").style.visibility=(document.formName.checkboxName.checked) ? "visible" : "hidden";
 }
```

but this solution does not work in JSFiddle.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: where is the fiddle?

Comment: This is the fiddle that I have: http://jsfiddle.net/ljnissen/vcjpoooy/

Comment: `paragraphName` should be `paragraphId`, you need an id here, not name.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/vcjpoooy/4/

Comment: Exactly. Thanks sanki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML

```
<label><input id="chk1" name="chk1" type="checkbox" onclick="nhamnham()"/>Hide p</label>
<p id="par">Text in the paragraph...</p>
```

The JS

```
function nhamnham() {
   if(document.getElementById("chk1").checked) {     
       document.getElementById("par").style.visibility="hidden";
   } else {
       document.getElementById("par").style.visibility="visible";
   }
}
```

Check here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzj7mb4n/)

Comment: Some notes: better avoid inline event handlers; checkboxes can change in other ways other than click; `input` elements have no content nor closing tag; you can use ternary operator to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
window.onload = function init() {
  checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
  checkbox.checked = true;
  checkbox.onchange = function(){
     document.getElementById("first").style.display = checkbox.checked?'block':'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but it's a little bit verbose. I prefer the one by Henriquedsg89.

Comment: Yep. I also prefer Henriquedsg89's way.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `init()` function{as per the fiddle link you provided} on `onclick` of checkbox:

```
<form name="formex">
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="firstpara" onclick="init();" />First paragraph<br/>
</form>
<p id="first">This is a paragraph</p>
```

And JS be like:

```
function init() {

if(document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked === false) {   
    document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'none';
}

else
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'block'; 

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcjpoooy/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a CSS-only solution:

```css
#toggler ~ #toggler-target {
  display: none;
}
#toggler:checked ~ #toggler-target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggler" />
<label for="toggler">Toggle</label>
<p id="toggler-target">Foo bar baz</p>
```

Comment: That is neat, but I would like to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var par = document.getElementById('par');
document.getElementById('chk1').addEventListener('change', function() {
   par.style.visibility = this.checked ? "hidden" : "visible";
});
```

```html
<label><input id="chk1" name="chk1" type="checkbox">Toggle</label>
<p id="par">Text in the paragraph...</p>
```